# How to check if a String must be completed with format method dynamically?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I've the following strings:

```
s = "The device %s was opened."
```

1. Are there the possibility to know if the String must be filled with format method?
2. If yes to the first question, are there the possibility to know how many `%s` exist in this string?

Comment: Unclear. Define "completed" and define "parameters". Is `%please-dont.use_me` a parameter?

Comment: Whether or not a string must be completed is for you to define, but yes, it is possible to count the number of tokens beginning with `%`.

Comment: @Tunaki i've changed in the question. Completed = Filled and parameters = %s. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Well, define "filled" now...

Comment: I don't get the question. Are you looking for an automatic method? If so, how would you know which parameters must be specified?

Comment: Yes. I thought in a automatic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code sample to check that your string contains '%s' symbol and return count of them.

```
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Test {

        public static void main (String[] args) {

            String s = "%s my string with %s";

            int i = 0;
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%s");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            while (m.find()) {
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

no.

### More Details

You cannot tell if a string "must be filled with a format method" because,
the fields used to mark insert points for the <strike>printf</strike> format method are potentially valid string content.
Here is an example:

```
The insert point for a String parameter is "%s"
```

This string does not need to be formatted,
but contains a valid insert point.

### The Answer You Want

Every insert point for the String.format method contains a percent sign (%),
but the format string is fairly complex.
You will need to parse the string and search for insertion points.

Try searching google for the Formatter.java source.

Here is the API page: [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

To know if a string contains %s use:

```
s.contains("%s")
```

To count number of "%s" in a String, you can use:

```
s.split("%s").length - 1;
```

The second part should be used only if contains returned true.
For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String s = "ssss %s %s gg";
boolean b = s.contains("%s");
int count = 0;
if (b)
{
    count = s.split("%s").length - 1;
}
System.out.println("b: " + b);
System.out.println("count: " + count);
}
```

Comment: Simply counting the ocurrances of %s is not a solution for at least two reasons, the % can be excaped: "%%s"; and a string may contain %s literally not meant to be replaced.

Comment: Well, the question was: "is there a possibility to know how many %s exist in this string"...